# Identifying worker nodes from Ansible inventory group which are not yet joined to k8s cluster using ansible.builtin.regex_search and regex_replace

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I am using Ansible to configure a k8s cluster with several nodes. I have a playbook which checks if a variable representing the `kubeadm join` command has already been defined. If it has not, it generates the `kubeadm join` command on the node in the `manager` group, then checks the output of `kubectl get nodes --no-headers` to identify nodes already joined. I intend to compare that output to the members of the `workers` group in `inventory.yml`, but I am struggling with the regex.

**I have two questions:**

1. Is this the best way to do this? I don't want to blindly execute the command on the nodes in `workers` since this will fail if the nodes are already joined, and further this fails idempotency.
2. If this is a good way to do this, can I get some help understanding where my regex is failing?

`inventory.yml`

```
workers:
    hosts:
        kube02.local:
        kube03.local:

manager:
    hosts:
        kube01.local:

kube:
    children:
        workers:
        manager:
```

relevant part of the playbook

```
   
- name: Creates join command by creating a token and printing the command
  ansible.builtin.shell: kubeadm token create --print-join-command
  register: k8s_join_command
  when: (k8s_join_command is undefined) and (inventory_hostname in groups['manager'])
  
- name: Creates variable from output of `kubectl get nodes --no-headers` on manager
  become: no 
  ansible.builtin.shell: kubectl get nodes --no-headers
  register: cluster_members
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['manager']

- name: Debug cluster members
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ cluster_members.stdout_lines | type_debug }}"
  when: k8s_join_command is defined

- name: Debug cluster members regex for matching against
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ cluster_members.stdout_lines | ansible.builtin.regex_replace('^(?P<name>kube[0-9]{2}).*$', '\\g<name>\\.local', multiline=True, ignorecase=True) }}"
  when: (inventory_hostname in groups['manager']) and (k8s_join_command is defined) and (cluster_members is defined)
```

output of playbook execution

```
TASK [k8s : Debug cluster members regex for matching against] **************************************************************************
skipping: [kube02.local]
skipping: [kube03.local]
ok: [kube01.local] => {
    "msg": [
        "kube01   Ready   control-plane   7d14h   v1.27.3",
        "kube02   Ready   <none>          7d1h    v1.27.3",
        "kube03   Ready   <none>          7d1h    v1.27.3"
    ]
}

TASK [k8s : Creates variable from output of `kubectl get nodes --no-headers` on manager] ***********************************************
skipping: [kube02.local]
skipping: [kube03.local]
changed: [kube01.local]

TASK [k8s : Debug cluster members] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [kube02.local] => {
    "msg": "AnsibleUndefined"
}
ok: [kube03.local] => {
    "msg": "AnsibleUndefined"
}
ok: [kube01.local] => {
    "msg": "list"
}

TASK [k8s : Debug cluster members regex for matching against] **************************************************************************
skipping: [kube02.local]
skipping: [kube03.local]
ok: [kube01.local] => {
    "msg": [
        "kube01   Ready   control-plane   7d14h   v1.27.3",
        "kube02   Ready   <none>          7d1h    v1.27.3",
        "kube03   Ready   <none>          7d1h    v1.27.3"
    ]
}
```

I'd expect to have output of the last task that is something like below, which I could then use to exclude `kube01.local` and execute the relevant command on `kube02.local` and `kube03.local`

```
TASK [k8s : Debug cluster members regex for matching against] **************************************************************************
skipping: [kube02.local]
skipping: [kube03.local]
ok: [kube01.local] => {
    "msg": [
        "kube01.local",
        "kube02.local",
        "kube03.local"
    ]
}
```

I've tried countless permutations of my regex, all of which are successful in my testing outside of Ansible, and all of which fail in a variety of ways *in* Ansible.